# Error deserializing Google-services.json file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

Tried to follow the instructions to setup Push notification through the MS App center. So I created an app in the Firebase console as per the instructions, and then downloaded the google-services.json file from there. Copied it over to my project and fixed the build action to GoogleServicesJson. Completed the rest of the setup in Firebase, App Center and in my code. But when I tried to build, I got the following error- `There was an error deserializing the object of type Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks.GoogleServices`.

The stack trace gave me this information:

`There was an error deserializing the object of type Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks.GoogleServices. Encountered an unexpected character 'ï' in JSON. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Encountered an unexpected character 'ï' in JSON.`

but I dont see ï anywhere in the file. Searched the issue and found people using a parser to fix this, but I'm not sure where to apply said parser.
Any one face this before?

Here's what the file looks like

```
{
  "project_info": {
    .. Configuration info ..
  },
  "client": [
    {
      .. Lots of lines ..
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Comment: I would assume that the json file has a BOM (unicode) sequence. Open the file in an editor (vi, etc..) that allows you to re-save it as an ascii / UTF-8 / etc encoded file (not a unicode based one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I right clicked on the file in Visual Studio, and Selected "Hex Editor".
Lo and behold, the `ï` was the first character of the file along with `>>` and `?` before the opening brace: `{`

So I deleted the extra characters until the opening brace, and the error was resolved. Onto other errors now...

Comment: where was this character even coming from? You may have resolved it now but do you think it may arise again? If yes then I would use a string replace function on the original string and then save it @Saamer

Comment: @NSDumb It is a BOM header on the file, I would assume it was opened in Visual Studio and re-saved as it is not this way it is when downloaded from google/firebase.

Comment: Yes that's close to what happened. Since I was waiting for the director for permission, I created the google-services.json file in Visual Studio and then just copied over its contents when I got it. And I realized that visual studio automatically creates that character when it's viewed in a hex editor. And yes, I verified, it does not happen if you just Add File from Visual Studio instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, for me it was because another .cs file was accidentally selected to be build as googleservicesjson